# how to get the data from delete trigger?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0, entity-framework-5

Suppose I have a table tab(ID, Name, ...)
In delete trigger, I can get the delete data from temp table deleted like

```
declare @Name varchar(50)
select @Name = Name from deleted
```

Suppose I have a line in table like

```
(1, 'MyName), ...)
```

then in SL app, I issue a delete from WCF ria service with SubmitChange by detach the entity from entityset. But before doing so, I change Name to "Yourname". So code like

```
myinstance.Name="YourName";
Context.tabs.Detach(myinstance);
```

So I want to get the value "YourName" in trigger. 
How to resolve this problem.

Comment: A trigger can also get **multiple rows** in `deleted` - so which one does your statement `select @Name = Name from deleted` select, in such a case?? It's not clear - **do not** rely on a trigger being fired once per row - in SQL Server - it's not - it's fired **once per batch** and your trigger codes needs to be able to **deal with multiple rows** in those pseudo tables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change you made in the application doesn't matter. Delete works with information stored in the database not in the application. If you want to get the new value in the trigger you must first update the record and after that execute deletion.